# Use all full chunks of an iterator (potentially skipping the last)

Tags: iterator, rust

I want to split a `Vec` into some parts of equal length, and then `map` over them. I have an iterator resulting from a call to `Vec`'s `chunks()` method. This may leave me with a part that will be smaller than other parts, which will be the last element generated by it.

To be sure that all parts have equal length, I just want to drop that last element and then call `map()` on what's left.

Comment: although there's a better solution for your case, note the existence of [std::iter::take](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/struct.Take.html)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As [Sebastian Redl points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48102761/155423), checking the `len`gth of each chunk is the better solution for your specific case.

To answer the question you *asked* ("Use all but the last element from an iterator"), you can use [`Iterator::peekable`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) to look ahead one. That will tell you if you are on the last item or not and you can decide to skip processing it if so.

```
let things = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

let mut chunks = things.chunks(2).peekable();
while let Some(chunk) = chunks.next() {
    if chunks.peek().is_some() {
        print!("Not the last: ");
    } else {
        print!("This is the last: ")
    }

    println!("{:?}", chunk);
}
```

> To be sure that all parts have equal length, I just want to drop that last element

Always dropping the last element *won't* do this. For example, if you evenly chunk up your input, then always dropping the last element would lose a full chunk. You'd have to do some pre-calculation to decide if you need to drop it or not.

Answer (score 12):

You can `filter()` the chunks iterator on the slice's `len()` being the amount you passed to `chunks()`:

```
let things = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

for chunk in things.chunks(2).filter(|c| c.len() == 2) {
    println!("{:?}", chunk);
}
```

This prints

```text
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
```

As of Rust 1.31, you can use the [`chunks_exact`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact) method as well:

```
let things = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

for chunk in things.chunks_exact(2) {
    println!("{:?}", chunk);
}
```

This prints

```text
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
```

Note that the returned iterator also has the method [`remainder`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/slice/struct.ChunksExact.html#method.remainder) if you need to get the uneven amount of items at the very end.

Comment: That's even more explicit. Thanks!

Comment: You could also slice the input to a multiple of the chunk size and avoid a check at each step.

Comment: A possibly more explicit version than `filter` would be to use `take_while` with the same condition, though obviously `chunks_exact` is a direct solution to the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If the collection being iterated over implements [`std::iter::DoubleEndedIterator`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html), you can use the [`next_back()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.DoubleEndedIterator.html#tymethod.next_back) method for a solution that is (probably) marginally more performant than [Shepmaster's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103219/155423) and a little cleaner:

```rust
let things = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

let mut chunks = things.chunks(2);
let last = chunks.next_back().unwrap();
    
println!("Last: {:?}", last);
    
for chunk in chunks {
    println!("Not last: {:?}", chunk);
}
```

`next_back()` eats the last element of the iterator, so after calling `next_back()` the iterator can be used to iterate over everything else. The output of the segment above:

```
Last: [4]
Not last: [0, 1]
Not last: [2, 3]
```

Comment: Seems like a reasonable solution when your iterator implements `DoubleEndedIterator` (but not all iterators do!).

Comment: @Shepmaster Good point. The OP was using a `Vec` so no problems in his/her scenario, but the question title was for iterators generally so the answer should be general. I have updated my answer to mention the requirement.

Comment: The last part may only be dropped, if it is smaller than the choosen chunk `size` 2 and `things` is not empty: `if (things.len() % size) != 0 { chunks.next_back(); }`

Answer (score 3):

For this particular situation, `chunks_exact` is what you want to use right now.

For the more general case of "taking all but the last `n` items of an iterator", Itertools has a method just for this: [`dropping_back`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.dropping_back).

Note that unlike methods of `std::iter::Iterator`, `dropping_back` is evaluated eagerly. Take care if your iterator chain is computation-heavy.

Answer (score 2):

Since Rust 1.31.0, you can use [`chunks_exact()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks_exact) to leave out the last chunk if it is not full.