# cannot use `*last_node` because it was mutably borrowed

Tags: rust

Why does this happen?

cannot use `*last_node` because it was mutably borrowed

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node {
    data: i32,
    next: Link,
}

type Link = Option<Box<Node>>;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct List {
    size: i32,
    head: Link,
}

impl List {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        List {
            size: 0,
            head: None,
        }
    }

    pub fn push(&mut self, data: i32) {
        let new_head = Box::new(Node {
            data: data,
            next: self.head.take(),
        });

        self.head = Some(new_head);
        self.size += 1;
    }

    pub fn append(&mut self, data: i32) {
        let new_node = Some(Box::new(Node {
            data: data,
            next: None,
        }));

        let mut last_node = &mut self.head;
        while let Some(node) = last_node {
            match node.next {
                None => break,
                Some(_) => last_node = &mut node.next,
            }
        }

        match last_node {
            None => self.head = new_node,
            Some(node) => node.next = new_node,
        }
        self.size += 1;
    }

    pub fn pop(&mut self) -> Option<i32> {
        let head = self.head.take();
        head.map(|node| {
            self.head = node.next;
            self.size -= 1;
            node.data
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut list = List::new();
    list.push(1);
    println!("{:?}", list);
    list.push(2);
    println!("{:?}", list);
    println!("{:?}", list.pop());
    list.push(3);
    println!("{:?}", list);
    list.push(4);
    println!("{:?}", list);
    list.append(5);
    println!("{:?}", list);
}
```

**gives error**

```
error[E0503]: cannot use `*last_node` because it was mutably borrowed
  --> src/main.rs:48:13
   |
40 |         while let Some(node) = last_node {
   |                        ---- borrow of `last_node.0` occurs here
...
48 |             None => self.head = new_node,
   |             ^^^^
   |             |
   |             use of borrowed `last_node.0`
   |             borrow later used here

error[E0499]: cannot borrow `last_node.0` as mutable more than once at a time
  --> src/main.rs:49:18
   |
40 |         while let Some(node) = last_node {
   |                        ---- first mutable borrow occurs here
...
49 |             Some(node) => node.next = new_node,
   |                  ^^^^
   |                  |
   |                  second mutable borrow occurs here
   |                  first borrow later used here

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors

Some errors have detailed explanations: E0499, E0503.
For more information about an error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

**But this does not give error:**

```
pub fn append(&mut self, data: i32) {
        let new_node = Some(Box::new(Node {
            data: data,
            next: None,
        }));

        let mut last_node = &mut self.head;
        while let Some(node) = last_node {
            last_node = &mut node.next
            //match node.next {
            //    None => break,
            //    Some(_) => last_node = &mut node.next,
            //}
        }

        match last_node {
            None => self.head = new_node,
            Some(node) => node.next = new_node,
        }
        self.size += 1;
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding an append method to a singly linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43976787/adding-an-append-method-to-a-singly-linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

The borrow checker is finicky about conditional mutable re-borrows. Your second version that doesn't error is close to correct though:

```
pub fn append(&mut self, data: i32) {
    let new_node = Some(Box::new(Node {
        data: data,
        next: None,
    }));

    let mut last_node = &mut self.head;
    while let Some(node) = last_node {
        last_node = &mut node.next;
    }

    *last_node = new_node;
    self.size += 1;
}
```

See it in full on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2d63c971c2cdf519b51892053578fc57).

I believe that the core issue with the original is that, because of the conditional match, the borrow checker considers *both* `last_node` and `last_node.next` to be borrowed at the same time even if they're actually the same variable. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64811086/2189130) for more information on this concept.

What you had written wasn't flawed, its just not currently accepted by the borrow checker.