# iterate over all but the last element

Tags: rust

In rust, how do I iterate all over the all but the last `n` elements?

```rust
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].iter().???(n)
```

---

Similar but not the same as [*Use all but the last element from an iterator*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102662/use-all-but-the-last-element-from-an-iterator) which is actually about matching chunk sizes. The content of that Question is "*To be sure that all parts have equal length, I just want to drop that last element and then call map() on what's left.*". All the proceeding answers use variations of `chunk` in their sample code. Reviewing those code samples, I found them too difficult to apply to my needs. Hence this new question with my Answer that does not use `chunk`.

Comment: In how far does the linked Q&A not suffice, especially the accepted answers suggestion to peek at the next item?

Comment: "which is actually about matching chunk sizes." the accepted answer from shepmaster literally solves your problem as-is (as it answers the problem as titled), it never even looks at chunk sizes. The second and not-accepted answer filters based on chunk sizes.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi
The linked question is regarding matching chunk sizes but has a misleading title. This question is not about chunk sizes. This question is not a duplicate.

Comment: @Masklinn you wrote "_it never even looks at chunk sizes._" referring to this Answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/48103219/471376). That Answer has with `chunks(2)` in the code.

Comment: The chunks are just the incidental iterable of that question. If you think a generic iterable answer is needed, why not post it there?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi "_If you think a generic iterable answer is needed, why not post it there?_"  These are different questions with overlapping but different solutions/Answers. The other question explicitly requests "_To be sure that all parts have equal length, I just want to drop that last element and then call map() on what's left._". That is a different problem than the Question here "_iterate all over the all but the last n elements?_". That is why the Answers for the other Question all involve using `chunk`.  Your insistence on downvoting this question is frustrating.

Comment: @JamesThomasMoon I haven’t downvoted this question (and didn’t even close ). But that you think so is certainly a sign that I should stop trying to work with you on salvaging this.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi oh I'm sorry, I had presumed you had. Just feeling a little frustrated. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Either:

```rust
array[..array.len() - n].iter()
```

```rust
array.iter().take(array.len() - n)
```

```rust
array.iter().rev().skip(n).rev()
```

Comment: I also will probably add `rtake` method to `dish` crate.

Comment: try yourself your last method see if its work

Comment: @stargateur, [it works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=5589a62fbbbbf1383747c6f7f04516ef)

Comment: it doesn't you removed the first element...

Comment: @stargateur, it was __*exactly*__ what OP asked for. Get last `n` elements. [Try to replace 3 with 2 and it will print last two](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=2dc879cace8ead2a8041b468f4b5e7e8).

Comment: no it's not what OP ask that the contrary

Comment: @Miiao The question asks for "all **but** the last n elements". That means excluding the last n elements.

Comment: @mistermiyagi, understood, fixing

Answer (score -3):

*tl;dr* [`take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take) the `len - n` iterations

```rust
fn print_elements_not_last_n(elems: &[i32], n: usize) {
    for elem in elems.iter().take(elems.len() - n) {
        println!("{:?}", elem);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let elems: [i32; 5] = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4];

    print_elements_not_last_n(&elems, 1);
    println!();
    print_elements_not_last_n(&elems, 2);
}
```

This prints

```text
0
1
2
3

0
1
2
```

You can also use [`iter().count()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count) instead of `len`. Using `count` might be necessary for code that processes an Iterable instead of a Sequence.

Comment: Actually in this case it only iterates once because `count` is special-cased for slices…

Comment: Replace `iter().count()` with `len()`